# Unable to get query string: pathname is filled but search is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react router + redux + redux saga. I access the location object passed as props to my component, where I try to get the query string part of the URL.

However, the search parameter of location is always empty. Nonetheless the pathname is filled as follows:

```
{pathname: "/view/energy?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11", search: "", hash: "", key: "wsbbq0"}
```

Any help or debug tip is appreciated. Thanks!

Libs versions:

```
"react-redux": "^7.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"redux-saga": "^1.1.3"
```

Index

```js
ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
         <Route path="/" component={App} />
         <Route path="/view/:viewId" component={App} />
      </Router>
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) it *should have* split your url into

```
{
  pathname: "/view/energy",
  search: "?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11",
  hash: "",
  key: "wsbbq0"
}
```

but that didn't occur.

The reason it didn't occur is because you are using the `to` object form and have specified the queryString as part of the `pathname` property, and then explicitly specified an empty string for the `search` property. Never the less, consider the following way to navigate to a pathname+search:

- ```
   <Link to="/view/energy?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11">
     View Energy
   </Link>
  ```

  Correctly parses the target path string into its constituent parts:

  ```
  {
    "pathname": "/view/energy",
    "search": "?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11",
    "hash": "",
    "key": "qje5v8"
  }
  ```
- ```
   <Link
     to={{
       pathname:
         "/view/energy?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11"
     }}
   >
     View Energy
   </Link>
  ```

  Failed to separate the queryString:

  ```
  {
    "pathname": "/view/energy?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11",
    "search": "", // <-- empty string
    "hash": "",
    "key": "f6eqol"
  }
  ```
- ```
   <Link
     to={{
       pathname: "/view/energy",
       search: "?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11"
     }}
   >
     View Energy
   </Link>
  ```

  Correctly maintains the target path object's constituent parts:

  ```
  {
    "pathname": "/view/energy",
    "search": "?latitude=34.06012&longitude=-118.26997&zoom=11",
    "hash": "",
    "key": "9qlzx8"
  }
  ```

[image: Edit unable-to-get-query-string-pathname-is-filled-but-search-is-empty]

Comment: Hi Drew, Thanks for the answer. It seems that params also includes url parameters (e.g. /:urlParameter/?querystring). I've noticed that in componentDidMount and componentWillMount the search parameter is correctly filled, however when I call it from render() it's not. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, it seems something related to the component lifecycle. As I mentioned in componentWillMount or DidMount it works fine. However in the render it's broken. Perhaps a react router bug.

Comment: @RicardoMayerhofer does this occur only locally or are you able to reproduce it in other projects or in an online codesandbox?