# How to listen to query param change event in react-router v5

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'd like to be able to listen to query param change events, preferably via a hook, but anything would be nice. I can't find anything that suggests it's even possible with react-router, so other suggestions without it are welcome too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing in `react-router-dom@5` that directly does this, so you'd need to implement this yourself. You can use the `useLocation` hook to access the `location.search` value to create a `URLSearchParams` object, then a `useEffect` hook to issue the side-effect based on any specific queryString parameter updating.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const { search } = useLocation();
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
const param = searchParams.get("param");

useEffect(() => {
  // issue side-effect
}, [param]);
```

For RRDv5 there is this recipe to abstract the access of the query params:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const useQuery = () => {
  const { search } = useLocation();
  return useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search]);
};
```

...

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '../path/to/hooks';

...

const searchParams = useQuery();
const param = searchParams.get("param");

useEffect(() => {
  // issue side-effect
}, [param]);
```

You can use `useQuery` and the `useEffect` hook to create another custom hook.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useQuery } from '.';

const useQueryParam = (paramKey, cb) => {
  const searchParams = useQuery();
  const param = searchParams.get(paramKey);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (param) {
      cb(param);
    }
  }, [param]);
};
```

...

```
import { useQueryParam } from '../path/to/hooks';

...

useQueryParam(
  "myParameter",
  (paramValue) => {
    // do something with "myParameter" param value
  },
);
```

Comment: I like this pattern, i'll certainly be using it going forward. However, it didn't fix the issue I was having here. After further investigation, i realised there's a problem with react-router's location object - console logging `location.search` returns `null` but `window.location.search` gives me the query string as expected. I found another answer by you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911283/unable-to-get-query-string-pathname-is-filled-but-search-is-empty and that is what the problem seems to be.

Comment: @Nodeocrat Hey, thanks for that information. I took another look at that other answer you linked to and have just updated it with what I believe is a plausible reason for the `location.search` being unpopulated. Glad both answers together have helped you though. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

did you tried below

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

    function MyComponent() {
      const location = useLocation();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Location changed');
      }, [location]);
    
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Only one thing to add, inside the dependency array use `location.search` instead of `location` for better readibility.